# Removing Conda "base" environment

Tags: terminal, virtualenv, conda

I'm trying to remove my entire Conda "base" environment. Every time I go into my terminal on my Mac, it says (base) ______________@_____________'s MacBook Pro. I did `conda deactivate`, then which the (base) no longer appeared before my name. Then I did `conda remove --name base --all`, and I got an error that says: `CondaEnvironmentError: cannot remove current environment. deactivate and run conda remove again`. I already deactivated my environment. Can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get rid of the **base** environment you need to uninstall Anaconda. To do it properly look at https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/uninstall/

If you just want to revert your **base** environment back to the original state before you installed any additional packages, try

```
conda install --name base --revision 0
```