# Removing a Conda environment

Tags: visual-studio-code, anaconda

Want to remove all the conda envs I have on my computer. It is just making my VS Code beginner experience bad. I want to streamline everything in VS Code.

But when I list my envs in terminal window I get this output:

[image: Code]

How do I remove these envs ? I just need a simple explanation and also want to have just one environment as of right now for my VS Code python project dev.

I referred to these links:

[Removing Conda environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49127834/removing-conda-environment)

https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/4.6.0/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#viewing-a-list-of-your-environments

Comment: Please if somebody can hop over a call to help me out. I beg !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing Conda "base" environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72777777/removing-conda-base-environment)